# How to see imported Oracle tables

Tags: oracle, import, oracle10g, toad, plsqldeveloper

I have oracle dump file from Oracle8. I am trying to import data in Oracle 10. For importing data I am using PL/SQL Developer(buy the way, I have TOAD client). I am doing that by click Tools->Import Tables choose Oracle Import, and then choose Import file. after that click Ok, Done. so How I can find imported tables?
I am using "sys" login. Database is located remotely.

**UPDATE1**
Ok. During importing I got this log

```
Export file created by EXPORT:V08.01.07 via conventional path
import done in CL8MSWIN1251 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
import server uses WE8MSWIN1252 character set (possible charset conversion)
export client uses WE8ISO8859P1 character set (possible charset conversion)
export server uses WE8ISO8859P1 NCHAR character set (possible ncharset conversion)
. importing SYSTEM's objects into SYSTEM
. importing MD's objects into MD

*****
Then
"ALTER SESSION .....
....there some sql syntaxes

. . skipping table "MyTable" 
****
WHY it is skipping?
****
end last
Import terminated successfully with warnings. :)
```

**UPDATE2.** The Issue was resolved by installing Oracle8 in virtual machine. Import was success.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to find them by creation time, if you haven't had these tables in your database before:

```
select object_name, created, last_ddl_time, timestamp
  from all_objects
 where owner = 'SYS'
   and object_type = 'TABLE';
```

And, yes, as it has already been said, don't use SYS for day-to-day operations. It's not a good practice at all.

Comment: The import might have created them under a different schema though, in which case you probably want to query the owner rather than restrict by it? (Personally I'd probably use `dba_objects` for this, look for any object type, and restrict or order by `created`, but whatever works).

Comment: Sure, my goal was just to give an idea to play with, not a complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

Imported tables aren't going to be flagged in any particular manner.  The import process itself knows what tables are loaded-- if you use the command-line import utility, you can have it generate a log of the objects that are imported.  I would expect that your GUI would have a similar log functionality.

I'm hoping that you are not importing the objects into the SYS schema or using SYS for normal day-to-day operations.  SYS is a very special, very powerful account.  It should be used very rarely and only for a handful of administrative tasks.

Comment: hopefully I did not import to any schema .

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the export was done as a different user and the objects have **not** been imported under the `SYS` schema. Doing that - or pretty much anything - as `SYS` is generally not advisable as there are a lot of ways you can damage your database.

If you know the original owner of the objects, look under the 'Other users' at the bottom of the schema list for your connection (in the left-hand panel), find and expand that user, and the tables should be in there. I have to add that I haven't imported that way, but with the command-line `imp` tool you get a warning about importing as a different user and that would tell you the original owner. Was there a log from this import?

Comment: as I see I haven't imported tables in any schema. So I did not damage SYS. I have created new user and trying import to it user(using fromuser= , touser= in IMP), currently have error with encoding. Buy the way plsqldeveloper uses IMP to import tables.

Comment: Sorry, misread that as 'SQL Devleoper'; ignore the bit about the connection panel then. Your post implied the import had worked and you just didn't know where the tables have gone. @be here now's approach of querying `all_tables` or `dba_tables` will help find anything you have created.